# resize an image client side and pass it to asp mvc controller with form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I am trying to resize an image client side before passing it to my controller (images uploaded will be large and many of them).

I have looked around and found this being discussed on various threads. After taking a number of solutions and trying to apply them to my scenario, I have realised I need a little more help.

I am allowing the user to add multiple files to the site but due to the size of these files (images), when I tried to make an Ajax call I found I was getting the error

> Maximum request length exceeded.

So I have decided to reduce their size on the client side before passing them to the server. The code below seems to have no effect, I see this is creating a new image and not altering the image being passed. How do I reduce the size of the passed images?

I am also open to alternative solutions to this problem, I want to avoid plugins as they seem a bit OTT for a "simple" image resizing

Below is my code:

**myPartialView.cshtml**

```
<input class="imgInput" type="file" name="FileUpload" multiple accept="image/jpeg" />
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Rooms[i].RoomID)
```

**myJavascript.js**

```
$("#accordion").on("change", ".imgInput", function (e) {
    var roomID = $(this).siblings("input:hidden").val();
    var images = $(".imgInput");

    // from an input element
    var filesToUpload = images[0].files;
    var file = filesToUpload[0];

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) { img.src = e.target.result }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;

    if (width > height) {
        if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
        }
    } else {
        if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }
    }
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");

    $("#roomIdentifier").val(roomID);
    var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#takeOn').get(0)) // store form data to pass on to the controller
    var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jQuery('#takeOn').serializeArray()));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Property/_RoomImage",
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'html',
        encode: true,
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#accordion").html(data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert("Error: " + request)
            alert("Error: " + status)
            alert("Error: " + error)
        }
    });

    //clear input value
    var input = $(this);
    input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
    //clear identifier
    $("#roomIdentifier").val('');
});
```

**myControllerForPartialView.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _RoomImage(TakeOn to, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload)
{
    /*does some stuff*/
    return PartialView("_Rooms", to);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to increase the maximum request size for that route? You could increase it only for that single route if you are concerned about increasing it for your entire app. Especially if the number of images is arbitrary; even shrinking them down you could eventually go beyond that request size.

But if you want to stick with resizing, then yes, you are correct--writing to a canvas and then getting the dataURL is not the same image. In fact, it won't POST as an image anymore. If you go this route, I would forget the file upload altogether. When the image is entered into your file input, create a hidden input and stick the data URL into that. Now POST a collection of those hidden inputs (as strings) instead of HttpPostedFileBase. And in your route, take those strings and convert them back to the images before saving them or whatever it is you are looking to do.